# Is there a way for me to set up an autoclicker on xbox one?

Tags: xbox-one, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I Play Bedrock Minecraft on Xbox One and no mater what any video says, you can NOT make a working afk Fish farm on bedrock with out an auto clicker. I've tried the rubber band technique and it wont work as you need to press it down multiple times for the rod to register. Its infuriating and i was wondering if you have any ideas. Also Im wondering if I could try plugging my iPhone in and coding a program to click it every so often. Any ideas where to start on that?
Any and all help would be welcome.

Answer (score 1):

A third-party Xbox 360 turbo controller can be used on a Windows 10 PC that's controlling a game running on an Xbox One by using Game Streaming in the Xbox App on the Windows 10 PC.

[How to use game streaming in the Xbox app on Windows 10](https://support.xbox.com/id-ID/xbox-on-windows/gaming-on-windows/how-to-use-game-streaming)

I've personally used the officially licensed Hori Pad EX2 Turbo controller with this method for various games. However, I don't know anything about fish farming in Minecraft so this approach may not work for that purpose.

Comment: Thank you but I would definitely be playing java if if i could on pc. I have a mouse and key board set up to my Xbox since my laptop broke. The only other option Ive seen is using a Titan Console tuner but at that point it seems hardly worth it. I hope that some bug or item comes out that lets us use afk fish farms again. Thank you for the help and again all advice is welcome.